# how to handle multiple fields in cql-solr for facet:pivot query

Tags: solr, cassandra, cql, cqlsh

I have tried solr-cql query with facte and one pivot field, it worked:

```
SELECT JSON id,department  FROM test.employee_copy1 WHERE solr_query = '{"q":"*:*", "facet":{"pivot":"firstname",limit":"-1"}}';
```

but how to get multiple fields in cql-solr for facet:pivot query, I am getting error code=2200, can not parse JSON query.

Query 1 :

```
SELECT JSON id,department FROM test.employee_copy1 WHERE solr_query = '{"q":"*:*", "facet":{"pivot":{"field":["firstname","lastname"]},limit":"-1"}}';
```

Query 2 :

```
SELECT JSON id,department FROM test.employee_copy1 WHERE d solr_query = '{"q":"*:*", "facet":{"pivot":{"field":["firstname","lastname"]},limit":"-1"}} GRROUP BY id';
```

Can anyone suggest me how to do this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Did formatting of json object in solr_query part and it worked for me.
Though groupby is yet pending.

employee_copy1 WHERE d solr_query = '{"q":"*:*", "facet":{"pivot":["firstname","lastname"]},limit":"-1"}} GRROUP BY id';

Thanks!